# Swift Send data from Popup to Another View

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to send data from popup view to DataView.
it actually works ! .However, when I go back to popup view to edit the text it doesn't show the text that was entered and sent to DataView.

I'm sending the data through protocol.

PopupView

```
protocol DataEnteredDelegate: class {
func userDidEnterInformation(data: String)}


@IBAction func DoneButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if let data = openTextView.text {
        delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(data: data)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

DataView

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openSummary" {
        let sendingVC: popupViewController = segue.destination as! popupViewController
        sendingVC.delegate = self
    }
}


// Protocol receving data from popup
    func userDidEnterInformation(data: String) {
    addJobSum.text = data
}
```

Comment: You dismissed the popup in the DoneButton handler. You will need to initialize the data in the new popup by setting the string values in the controls to the values you want.

Comment: Do you mean that I use prepare segue in the PopupView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the PopupViewController gets dismissed, it gets destroyed and no new instances are able to know what an old instance had as a text value for the Text View.

To fix it - create a string property inside `PopupViewController` and initialize the Text View's text property with its value inside some method, such as `viewDidLoad()`:

```
class PopupViewController: UIViewController {
    var textData: String?

    /* more code */

    func viewDidLoad() {
        /* more code */

        if let data = textData {
            openTextView.text = data
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you'll have to inject the proper / needed text for `textData` inside `prepare(for:)` method (right before it's presented):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openSummary" {
        let sendingVC = segue.destination as! PopupViewController
        sendingVC.delegate = self
        // This is the new line to be added: 
        sendingVC.textData = addJobSum.text
    }
}
```